# npm update includes pre-release

Tags: node.js, npm

There is a package, which has a latest version of 2.1.3, and a pre-release version of 3.0.0-rc.7. When I run `npm install package -g`, 2.1.3 is installed. When I run `npm update -g`, it updates to the pre-release (which I had installed previously, but removed later). Does npm keep a record of the pre-release being the latest?

```
$ package -v
2.1.3
$ sudo npm update -g package
$ package -v
3.0.0-rc.7
$ sudo npm remove package -g
$ sudo npm install package -g
$ package -v
2.1.3
```

The package registry gives `"latest":"2.1.3"` and `"pre":"3.0.0-rc.7"`. I'm using npm 1.4.13 and node 0.10.28.

Comment: I believe, but am not sure, that the code for `npm install` (without specifying a version/tag) will install the latest released version. And `npm update` will install the latest version, even if it's a pre-release.  I believe I've found the `npm update` code which gets the latest here: https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/outdated.js#L276, but can't locate the `npm install` code...

Comment: I also saw this happen with typescript.  npm install typescript gave v 2.0.8 (which had a dist tag of "latest").  Then npm update upgraded it to v 2.1.1 (which had a dist tag of "rc").  Very confusing indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an npm repository can keep several different dist-tags, with `latest` being the default when publishing and installing.   See [npm dist-tag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag) documentation.

The semver concept of a pre-release identifier and the npm concept of a non-default dist-tag are distinct, but it is probably a best-practice use them together if a package author chooses to [npm publish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish) any pre-release versions.  For example, when publishing a release-candidate, it might be appropriate to tag it with `next`.   For a more complex example, see the output from this command:

```
C:> npm dist-tag ls npm
3.x-latest: 3.9.6
3.x-next: 3.10.1
latest-1: 1.4.29
latest-2: 2.15.6
latest: 3.9.6
lts: 2.15.6
next-2: 2.15.8
next: 3.10.1
v3.x-latest: 3.9.6
v3.x-next: 3.10.1
```